# Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined error

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to delete a row from my "Customers" table with php and angular. this is the **error** that I get

> "Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined".

can someone know why?

this is my code:

**controller:**

```
$scope.delete = function(deletingId, index) {
        var params = $.param({"customer_id":deletingId});
        $http({
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          url: 'http://localhost:8081/hamatkin/api/delete-customer.php/',
          method: "GET",
          data: params
        }).success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
         $scope.customerDetails = data;
         $scope.customerDetails.splice(index, 1);
        });
      }
```

Customer.php

```
<?php
class Customer {

  private $table_name = "customers";

  public $customer_id;
  public $kind_Of_Customer;
  public $full_name;
  public $id;
  public $city;
  public $address;
  public $phone;
  public $phone_2;
  public $email;
  public $fax;
  public $referrer;
  public $comments;


}

?>
```

delete-customer.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

  include_once 'Customer.php';

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$customer = new Customer();


if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
   $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
   $del = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE customer_id='".$customer_id."'";
   mysql_query($connect, $del);
 }


$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/customerCards";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in customers | filter:search_query | orderBy: order_query:reverse_query">
            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.full_name}}</td>
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
                     <td><a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCardDetails/{{ x.customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary btn- active">הצג פרטי לקוח </a></td>
            <td><a ng-click="delete(x.customer_id, $index)" class="btn btn-primary btn- active">מחיקה</td>
```

when I use console.log(data)

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0041</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>256080</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-query' target='_new'>mysqli_query</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>5</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0069</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>256088</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-query' target='_new'>mysqli_query</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>6</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0095</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>256040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-query' target='_new'>mysqli_query</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>7</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php:6) in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php on line <i>23</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0115</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>257184</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.header' target='_new'>header</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\delete-customer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\delete-customer.php<b>:</b>23</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.data`is not defined, thus the error. It should be,

```
.success(function(data){

          data.splice(index, 1);
          $scope.customerDetails = data;

        });
```

Or,

```
.success(function(data){
          $scope.customerDetails = data;
          $scope.customerDetails.splice(index, 1);
        });
```

If data is not an Array, it will not work.

I guess it should be,

```
.success(function(data){
          console.log(data);

          $scope.customerDetails = data.data;
          $scope.customerDetails.splice(index, 1);
        });
```

Comment: thanks I changed to what you suggested but now it says: $scope.customerDetails.splice is not a function

Comment: This is because, $scope.customerDetails is not an Array. Can you console DATA post and show me response .

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what to do?

Comment: i mean write console.log(data). and check  it in browser console. Update your qus. with this value.

Comment: where to right it? in the console? I'm sorry I'm new with this

Answer (score 0):

This means that your `$scope.data` is undefined. Check that `$scope.data` has a value and is an array before you do the splice.

Also, I don't see a `$scope.data` in your code. The `data` that you get in the callback might be the one you need to splice.

Comment: thanks, I changed the code and I have different error $scope.customerDetails.splice is not a function

Comment: means `$scope.customerDetails` is not an array. Can you do a `console.log` on `$scope.customerDetails`?

Comment: do you mean console.log($scope.customerDetails)? and where to write it?

Comment: Yes. Print it in your app and post the output to your question

Comment: okay, so the data is a `string` . `Splice` is for an array and it wont work on a string

Answer (score 0):

$scope.data is not defined that's why it's throwing that error
use only data

`data.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: thanks, I changed to what @Ved said and now I have error - $scope.customerDetails.splice is not a function

Comment: either you are not able to fetch the data or the data that you are fetching is not an array , so you better first log the data.

Comment: You are fetching a whole page not data that's y you are getting like this, try linking to backend not to the php page.